# Spark stand alone cluster file access

Tags: apache-spark

I am researching to use Spark in my organization. 
One option is to use it as an stand alone cluster.
It seems to be clear - besides I have a lot of questions about that - that while creating a master and some slaves, Spark will take care of creating executors on the cluster members to manipulate the data.
My question is related to how the nodes access the file to be processed. As there is no HDFS to handle that, do I need to give access to every node to the file? For example NFS sharing it or by any other mean (copying to each node?).
Once the nodes have access to the file, how the cluster decide which part of the file to process, as there are no HDFS blocks to divide the data in.
Any light on this will be really appreciated.

Juan.

Answer (score 0):

> As there is no HDFS to handle that, do I need to give access to every
>   node to the file?

That's right. The options you've named though (NFS, local FS) aren't recommended beyond a PoC though.

> Once the nodes have access to the file, how the cluster decide which
>   part of the file to process, as there are no HDFS blocks to divide the
>   data in.

This has to do with file format (you want to use a splittable format). With a splittable format different executors will be able to read and process different pieces of a file in parallel.